# How can i convert the following sql statement to QueryDsl in java?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, querydsl

I tried to use querydsl from java code. but when using inner query with more the on column in select clause, I cant approach to specified columns. `r.maxTime` for example.

```
FROM (
      SELECT Train, MAX(Time) as MaxTime
      FROM TrainTable
      GROUP BY Train
) r
INNER JOIN TrainTable t
ON t.Train = r.Train AND t.Time = r.MaxTime
```

Comment: Can you show us the code you've already tried? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: my code is about different objects, I used this example in order to simplify things.

Comment: You tagged your question as java. At least one java sample might be helpful to people who want to help :)